# LINQ to SQL floating point rounding issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, floating-point-precision

I have a LINQ statement that has a few 'let's and some calculated columns.  I'm getting some rounding issues that I'm sure is due to precision or floating point math and I was hoping for an explanation.

To get around the issues, I first convert everything to decimal, then in the last step, convert the decimals back to doubles (after rounding done) to get rid of the 'precision' decimals that client didn't want.  So I'm currently 'functional'.

Here is a transact sql statement to illustrate the problem (285022.355 is the value I would have from previously calculated expressions and let statements):

```
select 285022.355 [Value From Previous Calculations],
        convert(float, 285022.355) [Simple Convert OK],
        round( 285022.355, 2 ) [Simple Round Works],
        round( convert(float, 285022.355), 2 ) [Simple Convert Round Does Not Work]
```

Producing following results:

Value From Previous Calculations: 285022.355
Simple Convert OK: 285022.355
Simple Round Works: 285022.360
Simple Convert Round Does Not Work: 285022.35

I would expect 285022.355 to round to 285022.36 and from my limited knowledge of 'floating point math problems', I thought it was always something like N.00000000001 (with a 'point 1' floating way at the end that could cause rounding UP problems).  How is converting '285022.355' to a float and rounding it to 2 decimals rounding DOWN to 285022.35?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using floats to begin with? I would never allow that if you are doing calculations. it never acceptable to use float in any math calculation.

Comment: So, in floating point math, `285022.355d` is stored as a value that is closer to `285022.35499999998`. It's the peril of using a decimal mindset in a binary world. Use decimals thoughout if rounding direction is important.

Comment: @HLGEM : That's a very decimal POV. It's perfectly acceptable to use floating point for math calculation. The limitations you allude to come from decimally minded folk expecting a perfect mapping between decimal representations and their floating point binary equivalent. Now, math of a financial nature? That's a different matter...

Comment: And if you are doing math, you want the real values not the estimates. And financial math it is even more important.

Comment: @HLGEM floats were used b/c I (probably mistakenly) used a double type in a c# LINQ statement and it converted to float.